Parallel random access of vector using indices that are guaranteed to not overlap
Context
I have implemented a broad phase collision detection algorithm that returns a nested vector (Vec<Vec<usize>>) of indices. I can guarantee that each index appears at most once within the nested vectors. I want to use these indices to index into a vector of bodies and perform narrow phase collision detection in parallel.
Problem
In a minimal example we would for each vector of indices, take a &mut reference to the element to form a vector of unique &mut references and perform narrow phase detection on this vector.
let bodies: Vec<u8> = vec![0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
let pass: Vec<Vec<usize>> = vec![vec![0,4],vec![2,3,5]];

pass.par_iter()
  .map(|indices| {
      let local_bodies: Vec<&mut u8> = 
          indices.iter().map(|i| &mut bodies[i]).collect();
      narrow_phase(&local_bodies)
});

But the errors I run into is 2-fold:

The &mut references to elements in bodies can't escape outside of the inner closure.
We can't borrow *bodies as mutable as it is a captured variable in a Fn closure

Question
What is the preferred way of doing this type of random access and mutating safely in rust? I would like to avoid the overhead of using Arc and Mutex. Additionally, I understand that the compiler can't guarantee safety by random access by itself but instead need some additional functionality (like Arcand Mutex).
Related Questions
Many go-to answers is to use build in chunks_mut and/or split_at_mut however I do not see them as applicable here as the indices are not sequential.
I found another question that seems to have the exact same problem, however the solution uses std::cell::Cell which does not implement the Sync trait.

I'm afraid unsafe is required here because, although not adapted to your use case, the implementation of split_at_mut() already (indirectly) relies on unsafe (after some checks on indices).

@prog-fh while it's true that split_at_mut uses unsafe, by that metric every use of Vec "uses unsafe".

@cafce25 I thought this could be understood in the context of mutably picking some non-overlapping elements inside a common slice (as split_at_mut() does), not in general...

I haven't used it personally so far, but the paradis crate aims to provide

Parallel processing with disjoint indices.

It offers both a low-level unsafe API and a high-level API that "[allows] many parallel access patterns to be expressed in safe code, or with a minimum of unsafe code".

This looks interesting! Although I would prefer to keep the number of dependencies  low, it serves as a good example
